# Airflow helm chart with multiple worker queue definitions

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am running Airflow with `CeleryExecutor` and they are package and deployed with helm charts. I have one worker that I can scale up/down by specifying the number of replicas in the yaml file. This worker is running as `StatefulSet` and by default it uses the `airflow` queue. Is it possible to create another `StatefulSet` chart for another worker and specify the queue name? This way for the DAG definition files, I can specify the queue to use as well.

Comment: Have you considered using [Kubernetes Executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#kubernetes-executor) instead?

Answer (score 0):

In your use case it would be better to use [Kubernetes Executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#kubernetes-executor) instead of splitting the worker management logic between `StatefulSets`.

> The kubernetes executor is introduced in Apache Airflow 1.10.0. The
>   Kubernetes executor will create a new pod for every task instance.

You can find more details about it in [this documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/kubernetes.html).

And also I recommend [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetesexecutor-for-airflow-e2155e0f909c).

I hope it helps.